# preg_replace for particular pattern if not exist

Tags: php, regex

I have the url inputs in various formats. I want to convert all into one standard format. Few example inputs are below.

- http://www.example.com
- https://in.example.com
- http://uk.example.com
- uk.example.com

From above all the inputs, I wish to convert into first one (http://www.example.com) with **www**. So I think we can replace the string if "www" not there.

```
$pattern = '/((http?|https)\:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z]+)\.example.com\/[a-z]{2}\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,30}/i';
```

I tried this pattern. I know it will match replace everything. SO please suggest me, how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function to_standard_format($url) {
    $pattern = '#(https?://)?\w+\.example.com(?=[/\s]|$)#i';
    return preg_replace($pattern, 'http://www.example.com', $url);
}

var_dump(to_standard_format('http://www.example.com'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('https://in.example.com'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('http://uk.example.com'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('http://uk.example.com/blah'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('uk.example.com'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('http://www.example.com.au'));
var_dump(to_standard_format('uk.another-example.com'));
```

prints

```
string(22) "http://www.example.com"
string(22) "http://www.example.com"
string(22) "http://www.example.com"
string(27) "http://www.example.com/blah"
string(22) "http://www.example.com"
string(25) "http://www.example.com.au"
string(22) "uk.another-example.com"
```

Comment: example.com will be change for each time like example1.com, So I can't replace it full path, Only I want to replace uk. or etc into www.

Comment: @gowri, I slightly updated the answer a few minute ago. Updated answer use positive lookahead assertion, and does not change the full path.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand, you just need to replace first part with "" (empty string). So you need pattern like https?://(www.)?

i.e. preg_replace("https?://(www.)?", "http://www.example.com", "")